# Truncated data in the POST request erlang

Tags: http, post, erlang, special-characters, ejabberd

I am trying to call an API from an ejabberd (17.04) module from erlang code by making a Post request. The API is called successfully, however, the data in the request body gets truncated.

Following is my erlang code to make the POST request.

```
Data = string:join(["to=", binary_to_list(To), "&from=", binary_to_list(From), "&body=", Body], ""),
Request = {binary_to_list(PostUrl), [{"Authorization", binary_to_list(Token)}], "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Data},
httpc:request(post, Request,[],[]),
```

I pass the data with the  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

There is no error while compiling or running the code, however, if there are some special characters in the `Body` variable, then the data is not sent to the API.

---

For example, when the `Body` variable contains the following value:

> {xmlel,<<\"encrypted\">>,\n       [{<<\"xmlns\">>,<<\"eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl\">>}],\n       [{xmlel,<<\"header\">>,\n               [{<<\"sid\">>,<<\"344245169\">>}],\n               [{xmlel,<<\"key\">>,\n                       [{<<\"rid\">>,<<\"684863397\">>}],\n                       [{xmlcdata,<<\"MwohBTL6tSWIPtugiO0qo0RNrWFC3ypIL5JpwMN1qF8jAoQ1EAAYASIwKnIw/zo43lF4At93Q7PMePlDVGF47Hf6xIvSjm+bpcESskndwFudirxigLSqc6J/P0IEL3sErsE=\">>}]},\n                {xmlel,<<\"iv\">>,[],\n                       [{xmlcdata,<<\"JR7NorYN19NBDwyY3eqXcg==\">>}]}]},\n        {xmlel,<<\"payload\">>,[],\n               [{xmlcdata,<<\"Da1s4qj6MiPgE1CP9S1ou5Cod//QAfmguc5GUGEk7IfTUJ8VU9CvL6iOfI3qK6Rg7uVNWACTWKBqCWGQstBkEEkwLDZHzJBqoJ6CoE4vxyfEdowWLqt84fNhGcsgvVxqmEDIln0NA2gDRd/vhGi0yIh2JdMQ55+6Ten1+fVb+kwYlKxe94XyMV84Yiz+bfPkAach22oYCZyMx695JSBnaUb8MRLISlnkcpLv/UJtmEMlGER/t5Ac5BK00sbkbVo4zOMbfOgA++prt4mbpceTGyJpmkRa/75xoqDPbYxG3sYujq52RguW1YO649M=\">>}]}]}

---

The `Data` variable contains the following value:

> "to=186&from=274&body={xmlel,<<\"encrypted\">>,\n       [{<<\"xmlns\">>,<<\"eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl\">>}],\n       [{xmlel,<<\"header\">>,\n               [{<<\"sid\">>,<<\"344245169\">>}],\n               [{xmlel,<<\"key\">>,\n                       [{<<\"rid\">>,<<\"684863397\">>}],\n                       [{xmlcdata,<<\"MwohBTL6tSWIPtugiO0qo0RNrWFC3ypIL5JpwMN1qF8jAoQ1EAAYASIwKnIw/zo43lF4At93Q7PMePlDVGF47Hf6xIvSjm+bpcESskndwFudirxigLSqc6J/P0IEL3sErsE=\">>}]},\n                {xmlel,<<\"iv\">>,[],\n                       [{xmlcdata,<<\"JR7NorYN19NBDwyY3eqXcg==\">>}]}]},\n        {xmlel,<<\"payload\">>,[],\n               [{xmlcdata,<<\"Da1s4qj6MiPgE1CP9S1ou5Cod//QAfmguc5GUGEk7IfTUJ8VU9CvL6iOfI3qK6Rg7uVNWACTWKBqCWGQstBkEEkwLDZHzJBqoJ6CoE4vxyfEdowWLqt84fNhGcsgvVxqmEDIln0NA2gDRd/vhGi0yIh2JdMQ55+6Ten1+fVb+kwYlKxe94XyMV84Yiz+bfPkAach22oYCZyMx695JSBnaUb8MRLISlnkcpLv/UJtmEMlGER/t5Ac5BK00sbkbVo4zOMbfOgA++prt4mbpceTGyJpmkRa/75xoqDPbYxG3sYujq52RguW1YO649M=\">>}]}]}"

---

However, when I try to fetch this value in my API, only the following data is available:

> {xmlel,<<\"encrypted\">>,\n       [{<<\"xmlns\">>,<<\"eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl\">>}],\n       [{xmlel,<<\"header\">>,\n               [{<<\"sid\">>,<<\"344245169\">>}],\n               [{xmlel,<<\"key\">>,\n                       [{<<\"rid\">>,<<\"684863397\">>}],\n                       [{xmlcdata,<<\"MwohBTL6tSWIPtugiO0qo0RNrWFC3ypIL5JpwMN1qF8jAoQ1EAAYASIwKnIw/zo43lF4At93Q7PMePlDVGF47Hf6xIvSjm+bpcESskndwFudirxigLSqc6J/P0IEL3sErsE

---

I am new to erlang and not sure of what seems to be the problem. Any help is appreciated.